# C# Convert singed hexa to decimal

Tags: c#, hex

I’m recieving from my device hexa data: `E8C6`.
It's supposed to be a negatine number.

I tried using `Convert.ToInt32(data, 16)` but I’m getting a large possitive instead.

Then I tried converting with `Sbyte` but I’m getting an overflow exception.

So what is the right way to convert?

Comment: 4 hex digits probably means `short` (aka `System.Int16`) so try `Convert.ToInt16()`.

Comment: ToInt16 == -5946

Comment: Which endian is this? as both will convert to a negative number

Comment: Great, thanks! Working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ToInt16()`

```
short result = Convert.ToInt16("E8C6", 16); //-5946
```

Comment: And if the OP needs it as an int32, `int result =(int)Convert.ToInt16("E8C6", 16);`, although strictly the `(int)` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you! Working!

Comment: Addendum: For the reason why, integers use the most significant bit to describe negative numbers. If you convert `E8C6` to a 32-bit int, it will be `0x0000E8C6` thus the MSB is 0. If you do it as a 16-bit int, it is `0xE8C6` and the MSB is 1.

Comment: @SashaVasserfirer please mark this as the Answer with the green checkmark to its left!

Comment: @SashaVasserfirer how about accepting my answer by clicking the green check?